# Android GeomagneticField not working

Tags: java, android, location

I am experiencing some problems using Android location-related APIs. Let me cut to the chase:

```
GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(20f, 20f, 0, System.currentTimeMillis());
float declination = geoField.getDeclination();
```

Those are testing values and they have no meaning whatsoever. The problem is that `getDeclination()` **always** returns 0, no matter what values of latitude, longitude or altitude I use to instantiate GeomagneticField.

I'm assuming the instance is created successfully (otherwise it would throw some sort of exception). So how is that possible?

Comment: values of getX() and getY()?

Comment: Strange however you can check here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/hardware/GeomagneticField.java

Comment: I want to specify that I'm experiencing this issue only when running unit tests with plain JUnit. If I try to debug that piece of code with an emulator, it all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. When unit testing using the Android APIs, you need to use the instrumentation framework. I was using JUnit alone, thus the malfunctioning. I resolved by using Roboelectric, a tool that sort of emulates the Android platform allowing you to run unit tests that use Android APIs without bringing up a device emulator every time.